# HASHBYTES in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, md5

Why is there a 2 at the end of the SQL command on line 2?
I found this set of code from a site.
Can someone explain the reason for putting the 2 in there?

```
UPDATE myTable
SET CryptPassword = CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', (SELECT Password)), 2)
GO
```

Comment: The argument 2 is to the CONVERT() function.

Comment: Curious why you have (SELECT Password)

Comment: Just for completeness: MD5 has been considered completely broken for cryptographic purposes for years now. This code may just be an example, but whatever you do don't actually use it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert What are people using instead of MD5 hash nowadays?

Comment: It depends on the purpose. For general-purpose hashing, the SHA-2 and SHA-3 family of hashes are recommended (SHA-1 is also considered broken and is being phased out). For storage of passwords specifically, the use of a [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) with at least a 64-bit salt is recommended. This cannot be implemented directly in SQL Server, as it doesn't offer such functions. Ideally passwords should be hashed only on the client side -- this makes upgrading algorithms easier and also avoids transmitting passwords in the clear to SQL Server.

Comment: You shouldn't (re)-implement a password hashing algorithm yourself; whatever your client technology, there are crypto libraries to help with such matters. Argon2 is a popular recent algorithm that has been widely implemented (but whatever you pick, room should be left for the option to move to newer algorithms when necessary).

Comment: Also don't store hashes in `varchar`. They are binary, store them in `binary` or `varbinary`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2 sets the style ... Take a peek at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Just for fun, you can compare the results

```
Select With1 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'MyPassword'), 1)  -- with 0X
      ,With2 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'MyPassword'), 2)  -- without 0x
      ,SansN = CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'MyPassword'))     -- binary (default)
```

**Results**

```
With1                               With2                               SansN
0x48503DFD58720BD5FF35C102065A52    48503DFD58720BD5FF35C102065A52D7    HP=ýXrÕÿ5ÁZR×
```

**Note:** since varchar(32), With1 is truncated (missing D7)

Comment: As I have the WHERE statement, the SELECT Password will select the password that's in that row.

Comment: @SiamParvez Fair enough... just seems unnecessary in my little head  :)

Comment: Is there any better way or am I doing it in the wrong way somehow?

Comment: @SiamParvez It's not "wrong" but MD5 was depreciated in 2019.   It would only take a few minutes to brute force 8 an character password.   You can use SHA2_256 or even SHA2_512 .   I am however a little concerned about the 32 characters.   Give yourself some wiggle room ...